# Azure web app container private Endpoint deployment doesn't work with private endpoint container registry

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

**The Setup I have:-**

- Azure web app container on a private endpoint that also has Vnet integration.
- private endpoint azure container registry.
- A self hosted azure devops virtual machine for running build jobs.
- The Github repos are linked to the azure devops account.

For this particular project, I am building and pushing the docker image to azure container registry and then deploying that image to the azure web app container. All of the components in the above system are on the same virtual network. I used this guide for the pipeline:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp-on-container-linux?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deploy-with-azure-web-app-for-container

**The problem:-**

The pushing of image to the container registry works. But the azure web app container is not able to pull the container registry image over the private network. It tries to do it over the public internet which is disabled in registry firewall. Below is the error message I get:-

```
DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, 
response={"message":"Get https://xxxx.azurecr.io/v2/docker_file_path/manifests/19: denied: client with IP 
'xx.xxx.132.231' is not allowed access. Refer https://aka.ms/acr/firewall to 
grant access."}
```

The IP `xx.xxx.132.231` is the public outbound IP of that azure web app so it's confirmed that it's tying to do so over the public internet.

**What I found:-**

I searched and found that another person had the exactly same error. The Microsoft team has been working on it since months but it still doesn't work yet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/280774/app-service-for-web-app-for-containers-container-r.html

**Question:-**

Is there any way I could make it work? Is there some other way of deployment for web app containers with private endpoint which can happen entirely over the virtual network? Thanks for reading.

Comment: There is no other way available as of now. you may submit a feedback here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/feedback/

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? Because I'm trying to solve the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Container Apps Virtual Network Integration Announced 2022-02-02

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-container-apps-virtual-network-integration/ba-p/3096932